# Change document title when title has been changed by another script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I have a Chrome extension which renames document title, but It doesn't work for websites which live-updates the title such as Facebook, AngularJS SPA...

So I need to detect this change to override it. The problem as you expect that it does an infinite loop:

```
var target = document.querySelector('head > title');

var observer = new window.MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        console.log(mutation.target.textContent);
        
        // here change the title with a new value
        document.title = 'something';
    });
});

observer.observe(target, {
    subtree: true,
    characterData: true,
    childList: true
});
```

Then, how could I tell to my event "Do nothing if I am the one who fired you"?

A bad way is to update the title every X seconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your own property to mark when you change a title:

```
if (typeof(document.titleChanged) == "undefined") {
    console.log(mutation.target.textContent);

    // here change the title with a new value
    document.titleChanged = true;
    document.title = 'something';
} else {
    delete document.titleChanged;
}
```